# Equivalence of W^{m,p} and H^{s,p} norms

Tags: sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces, fourier-transform

I am reading Cazenave's Semilinear Schroedinger Euqation.
On page xi the two norms are defined:

$\| u \|_{W^{m,p}} = \sum\limits_{|\alpha|\leq m} \| D^{\alpha} u \|_{L^p}$,

$\| u \|_{H^{s,p}} = \left\| \mathcal{F}^{-1} \left[ \left( 1+|\xi|^2 \right)^{\frac{s}{2}} \mathcal{F}u \right] \right\|_{L^p}$,

where $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ are the Fourier and inverse Fourier transforms, respectively.

On page 13 (Remark 1.4.1, (iv)) it is stated that from Mihlin's multiplier theorem and for non-negative integer $m$, the equivalence between the norms of $W^{m,p}(\mathbb R^N)$ and $H^{m,p}(\mathbb R^N)$ follows.

Mihlin's multiplier theorem claims that if $\sigma$ is a function defined in $\mathbb R^N\setminus\{0\}$ which has at least $[N/2]+1$ continuous derivatives satisfying

$|\partial^{\alpha}\sigma(\xi)|\leq C_{\alpha}|\xi|^{-|\alpha|}$, for all $|\alpha|\leq [N/2]+1$ ($[l]$ is the integer part of $l$), then

$\| T_{\sigma}(u)(x) \|_{L^p}\leq C \| u \|_{L^p}$ for functions $u\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^N)$, the constant $C$ depends on $\sigma$, $N$ and $p$, where

$T_{\sigma}(u)(x)=\int\limits_{\mathbb R^n}\hat{u}(\xi)\sigma(\xi)e^{2\pi i x\cdot\xi}d\xi=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\sigma\mathcal{F}(u))(x)$.

Unfortunately I don't understand how Mihlin's theorem assures the equivalence $\| u \|_{W^{m,p}}=\| u \|_{H^{m,p}}$, i.e. $\sum\limits_{|\alpha|\leq m} \| D^{\alpha} u \|_{L^p} = \left\| \mathcal{F}^{-1} \left[ \left( 1+|\xi|^2 \right)^{\frac{s}{2}} \mathcal{F}u \right] \right\|_{L^p}$.

Can someone please share how the proof is structured? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two norms are not equal, but they are equivalent which suffices in showing that $H^{m,p} = W^{m,p}.$ There are many sources for this, but one reference I think is quite clear is Theorem 6.2.3 of the following text:

*Bergh, Jöran; Löfström, Jörgen*, Interpolation spaces. An introduction, Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften. 223. Berlin-Heidelberg-New York: Springer-Verlag. (1976). [ZBL0344.46071](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0344.46071).

I will reproduce the argument here. To simplify notation we denote the associated *Bessel potential operators*
$$ J^{s}u = \mathcal F^{-1} \left( (1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac{s}2} \mathcal Fu(\xi)\right).$$
Note we have $\lVert u \rVert_{H^{m,p}(\Bbb R^N)} = \lVert J^mu\rVert_{L^p(\Bbb R^N)}.$

Given $|\alpha| \leq m,$ we can check that
$$ \sigma_{\alpha}(\xi) = \xi^{\alpha} (1+|\xi|^2)^{-\frac{m}2} $$
is a Mihlin multiplier; indeed it is smooth and $|\partial^{\beta}\sigma_{\alpha}| \leq C\min\{1,|\xi|^{|\alpha|-m-|\beta|}\} \leq C |\xi|^{-\beta}.$ Hence by the Mihlin multiplier theorem we have
$$ \lVert \partial^{\alpha}u \rVert_{L^p(\Bbb R^N)} = \lVert \mathcal F^{-1}\left(\sigma_{\alpha}(\xi) \mathcal F(J^mu)(\xi)\right)\rVert_{L^p(\Bbb R^N)} \leq C \lVert J^mu\rVert_{L^p(\Bbb R^N)}, $$
and so summing over all $|\alpha| \leq k$ gives
$$ \lVert u \rVert_{W^{m,p}(\Bbb R^N)} \leq C \lVert J^ku\rVert_{L^p(\Bbb R^N)} = C \lVert u \rVert_{H^{m,p}(\Bbb R^N)},$$
which proves one direction. For the converse let $\chi \in C^{\infty}(\Bbb R)$ be a cutoff such that $1_{(-1,1)} \leq 1-\chi \leq 1_{(-2,2)}$ and consider
$$\sigma_0(\xi) = (1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac{m}2} \left(1+ \sum_{j=1}^N \chi(\xi_j) |\xi_j|^m \right)^{-1}, \text{ and } \sigma_j(\xi) = \chi(\xi_j) |\xi_j|^m \xi_j^{-m}$$
for $1 \leq j \leq N.$ One can verify these are Mihlin multipliers, and that
$$ \left(1+\sum_{j=1}^N \sigma_j(\xi)\xi_j^m\right) \sigma_0(\xi) = (1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac m2}, $$
so we can compute
\begin{align*}
  \lVert J^mu \rVert_L^p(\Bbb R^N) &\leq C \left\lVert \mathcal F^{-1}\left(\left(1+\sum_{j=1}^N \sigma_j(\xi)\xi_j^m\right)\mathcal Fu\right)\right\rVert_{L^p(\Bbb R^N)} \tag{with $\sigma_0$} \\
&\leq C \left( \lVert \mathcal F^{-1}(\mathcal Fu)\Vert_{L^p(\Bbb R^N)} + \sum_{j=1}^N \lVert \mathcal F^{-1}(\sigma_j(\xi)\xi_j^m\mathcal Fu)\rVert_{L^p(\Bbb R^N)} \right) \tag{$\Delta$-inequality}\\
&= C \left( \lVert u\Vert_{L^p(\Bbb R^N)} + \sum_{j=1}^N \lVert \mathcal F^{-1}(\sigma_j(\xi)\mathcal F(\partial_j^mu))\rVert_{L^p(\Bbb R^N)} \right) \tag{Properties of $\mathcal F$}\\
&= C \left( \lVert u\Vert_{L^p(\Bbb R^N)} + \sum_{j=1}^N \lVert \partial_j^mu\rVert_{L^p(\Bbb R^N)} \right) \tag{with $\sigma_j$}\\
&\leq C \lVert u \rVert_{W^{m,p}(\Bbb R^N)},
\end{align*}
as required.

---

**Added later**: To prove the symbol estimates, the idea is not to explicitly compute the derivatives, but to separate the terms using the Leibniz rule and estimate the individual terms by an inductive argument. I will sketch the details to illustrate this for $\sigma_{\alpha};$ by the Leibniz rule we have
$$ \partial^{\beta}\sigma_{\alpha}(\xi) = \sum_{\gamma \leq \beta} {\beta \choose \gamma} \partial^{\beta-\gamma}\xi^{\alpha} \partial^{\gamma}\left( (1+|\xi|^2)^{-\frac m2} \right), $$
and we claim all the terms in the sum decay as $O(|\xi|^{-m+|\alpha|-|\beta|}).$ It is easy to see that $|\partial^{\beta-\gamma}\xi^{\alpha}| \leq C |\xi|^{|\alpha|-|\beta|+|\gamma|},$ noting that each partial derivative will decrease of the order of the polynomial *if* it is not already zero. Moreover noting the term vanishes if $|\alpha|-|\beta|+|\gamma|<0,$ we can also bound the term as
$$ |\partial^{\beta-\gamma}\xi^{\alpha}| \leq C(1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac{|\alpha|-|\beta|+|\gamma|}2}.$$
For the second term we claim by induction on $|\gamma|$ that for all $k$ we have
$$ \partial^{\gamma}\left( (1+|\xi|^2)^{-\frac k2} \right) \leq C(1+|\xi|^2)^{-\frac{k+|\gamma|}2}. $$
Here we write $\gamma = \gamma' + e_i,$ applying the inductive hypothesis for $\gamma'$ and $k+1.$

Putting everything together we arrive at the estimate
$$ \partial^{\beta}\sigma_{\alpha} \leq C (1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac{-m+|\alpha|-|\beta|}2} \leq C (1+|\xi|^2)^{-\frac{|\beta|}2}, $$
where we have used the fact that $|\alpha| \leq m$ in the last inequality.

For the other two terms we need to distinguish when each $|\xi_j| \leq 1$ or not; if $|\xi_j|<1$ then $\sigma_j(\xi) = 0$ and we can also since $\chi_j(\xi)=0$ the expression for $\sigma_0$ simplifies. If $|\xi_j|>1$ then $\chi_j(\xi)$ is just a smooth function whose derivatives can be bounded. One needs a similar induction argument to estimate the derivatives of $(1+\sum_{j=1}^N \chi_j(\xi)|\xi|^m)^{-1}$ (considering cases at each step), but I hope you can see how to fill in the details.

Comment: Thank you for the help @ktoi! A great proof and an excellent explanation! The only thing I don't understand is how to verify that $\sigma_{\alpha}(\xi)$, $\sigma_0(\xi)$ and $\sigma_j(\xi)$ are Mihlin multipliers.

It might not be that hard, but I cannot see it. Maybe one uses $\xi^{\alpha}(1+|\xi|^2)^{-\frac{m}{2}}\leq\xi^{\alpha}|\xi|^{-m}$ for $\sigma_{\alpha}(\xi)$. If it is not too much, I will be grateful for your support.

In this case $\alpha$ is a multi-index and $\xi^{\alpha}$ is a monomial of the form $\xi_1^{\alpha_1}\xi_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots\xi_N^{\alpha_N}$, is that correct?

Comment: @Candidate Indeed $\xi^{\alpha} = \prod_{i=1}^n \xi_i^{\alpha_i}.$ I sketched the estimate for $\sigma_{\alpha},$ but since each multiplier is smooth (by choice of cutoff) it suffices to check the decay at infinity. It may seem a bit confusing because $\sigma_{\alpha}$ actually has a faster decay than what's needed when $|\alpha| < m,$ but the idea is just to differentiate and check it decays correctly as $|\xi| \to \infty.$ The calculation is a bit messy, but for $\sigma_0, \sigma_j$ it can be simplified if you notice that for large $|\xi|$ you can mostly ignore the cutoff terms.

Comment: Actually my main concern with $\sigma_{\alpha}(\xi)$ is that any derivative of order greater than 2 gets quite complicated. So I assumed that the proof is easier and that I am missing something (especially if I have to calculate explicitly all derivatives). Anyway, I will try and complete the proof, as I am curious to see it. In any case, @ktoi thank you so much for your responsiveness, your help is of great importance for me! I hope we stay in touch :)

Comment: @Candidate I've edited my answer to sketch how to perform these estimates - the details are a bit messy but hopefully this clarifies things.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @ktoi! Again, excellent proof and easy-to-understand arguments.  :) Sorry I did not see your post earlier.
Thanks to your reply, I think now I understand where my confusion comes from (although I thought I am familiar with multi-index notation).

Comment: My reasoning is the following. The operator $\partial^{\beta-\gamma}$ acts like a vector and so $\partial^{\beta-\gamma}\xi^{\alpha}=\langle \partial_1^{\beta_1-\gamma_1}\xi^{\alpha}, \partial_2^{\beta_2-\gamma_2}\xi^{\alpha},\cdots, \partial_N^{\beta_N-\gamma_N}\xi^{\alpha} \rangle$ and for each $j$ we have $\partial_j^{\beta_j-\gamma_j}\xi^{\alpha_j}=\alpha_j(\alpha_j-1)\cdots(\alpha_j-\beta_j+\gamma_j+1)\xi_j^{\alpha_j-\beta_j+\gamma_j}$.

Comment: Hence $\partial^{\beta-\gamma}\xi^{\alpha}=\langle C_1 \xi_1^{\alpha_1-\beta_1+\gamma_1}, C_2\xi_2^{\alpha_2-\beta_2+\gamma_2},...,C_N\xi_N^{\alpha_N-\beta_N+\gamma_N}\rangle$ and $|\partial^{\beta-\gamma}\xi^{\alpha}|=\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^NC_j^2\xi_j^{2(\alpha_j-\beta_j+\gamma_j)}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq\max\{C_1, C_2,...,C_N\} \left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^N|\xi|^{2(\alpha_j-\beta_j+\gamma_j)}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq C\left(\sum\limits_{p\leq |\alpha|-|\beta|+|\gamma|}\binom{|\alpha|-|\beta|+|\gamma|}{p}|\xi|^{2p}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=C(1+|\xi^2|)^{\frac{|\alpha|-|\beta|+|\gamma|}{2}}$.

Comment: It was too long and I had to squeeze it in a couple of comments. I would very much appreciate if you share your opinion if the above and my understanding about $|\partial^{\beta-\gamma}\xi^{\alpha}|$, in particular, is correct. :) Thank you!

Comment: @Candidate Sorry for the late response, but your interpretation is not quite correct; $\partial^{\beta}\xi^{\alpha} = \partial_{\xi_1}^{\beta_1}\dots \partial_{\xi_n}^{\beta_n} \xi^{\alpha_1}_1 \dots \xi^{\alpha_n}_n = (\partial_{\xi_1}^{\beta_1}\xi_1^{\alpha_1}) \dots (\partial_{\xi_1}^{\beta_n}\xi_n^{\alpha_n}).$ This will either be $C\xi^{\alpha-\beta}$ or zero depending on whether $\beta_i \leq \alpha_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n.$

Comment: Hi @ktoi, you are completely right! :) Just one remark from me - as far as I understand when $C\xi^{\alpha-\beta}$ is zero, then it is certainly less than $C(1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac{|\alpha|-|\beta|+|\gamma|}{2}}$ and the statement is proved. And that is why I considered the non-trivial case when $C\xi^{\alpha-\beta}$ is different from zero. In any case, thank you for your help and your time, your insights helped me a lot and I really appreciate it! :)